# Inserción del código de paginación, en PHP con la librería del DOMPDF

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

¿Bastará agregar el código en la página PHP para que la paginación se envíe?

```
<script type="text/php">
    if (isset($pdf)){
        $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("Arial", "bold");
        $pdf->page_text(765, 550, "Pagina {PAGE_NUM} de {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 9, array(0, 0, 0));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Seguirá activa esta pregunta?

Comment: IMPORTANTE: Recuerda activar en la configuración de DOMPDF DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP = true o de lo contrario no ejecutará el código y no veremos la paginación.

Comment: ¿Será que el OP probó el código que indicó acá? ¿Por qué le daría a uno miedo probar un código para ver si se envía la paginación?

Answer (score 0):

**Descomentar** en

```
dompdf_config.custom.inc.php define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP", true);
```

Para que salga el número de la pagina

Answer (score 0):

`$dompdf->getCanvas()->page_text(15,800, "Página {PAGE_NUM} de {PAGE_COUNT}", null, 10, array(0,0,0));`

$dompdf->getCanvas(): Este método obtiene el "lienzo" o la superficie sobre la que se dibujará el PDF. Piensa en esto como obtener un acceso directo para dibujar o escribir en el documento PDF.

page_text(15,800, "Página {PAGE_NUM} de {PAGE_COUNT}", null, 10, array(0,0,0)): Este es el método que se está llamando sobre el lienzo. Se utiliza para agregar texto a cada página del PDF generado. Los parámetros que se pasan a este método especifican cómo y dónde se mostrará este texto:

15, 800: Estos son los valores de coordenadas x y y, respectivamente, que definen la posición del texto en la página. En este caso, el texto se colocará 15 unidades desde el borde izquierdo y 800 unidades desde el borde superior de la página.

"Página {PAGE_NUM} de {PAGE_COUNT}": Esta es la cadena de texto que se imprimirá. {PAGE_NUM} y {PAGE_COUNT} son marcadores de posición que Dompdf reemplazará automáticamente con el número de página actual y el número total de páginas, respectivamente.

null: Este parámetro normalmente especificaría la fuente a utilizar. Aquí, null significa que se utilizará la fuente predeterminada.

10: Este es el tamaño de la fuente del texto.

array(0,0,0): Este array define el color del texto en formato RGB. En este caso, (0,0,0) representa el color negro.

Comment: Saludos, por favor considera dar una explicación al código que agregaste, las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Chequea el uso de `getFont`, encuentra una lista de nombres de familia usados como parámetro en el método si no renderiza en el navegador es posible que algo en tu código esta incorrecto.

```
      if ( isset($pdf) ) {
        $h = $pdf->get_height();

        $size = 6;
        $font_bold = $fontMetrics->getFont("helvetica", "bold"); // intenta uno  diferente
        $text_height = $fontMetrics->getFontHeight($font_bold, $size);
        $y = $h - $text_height - 24;

        $pdf->page_text(550, $y, "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font_bold, $size, [0, 0, 0]); // longitud ingresada de la pagina
      }
```